# gdal2tiles.py how to find optimal zoom level for leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, gdal2tiles

I working on a project need to tackle with deal with geotiff image file.
I'm new to leaflet and geotiff image.I got an image from client and i need to overlay it to leaflet map from geotiff. I used

```
gdal2tiles.py -p raster [image.tif]
```

to generater tiles map. And i tried to display it on leafletmap, however I got this display[image: Displaying from react-leaflet]

I wondering anyone have idea to figure out, how to find out the optimal zoom level for convertion from geotiff to raster files without lossing it's quality?Here is my gdalinfo from my geotiff file.

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Geotiff.tif
Size is 25070, 18673
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 54N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",141],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32654"]]
Origin = (297884.090830000001006,3955249.192560000345111)
Pixel Size = (0.071710000000000,-0.071710000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=pix4dmapper
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  297884.091, 3955249.193) (138d45'55.76"E, 35d43'13.77"N)
Lower Left  (  297884.091, 3953910.152) (138d45'56.97"E, 35d42'30.34"N)
Upper Right (  299681.861, 3955249.193) (138d47' 7.26"E, 35d43'15.09"N)
Lower Right (  299681.861, 3953910.152) (138d47' 8.46"E, 35d42'31.66"N)
Center      (  298782.976, 3954579.672) (138d46'32.11"E, 35d42'52.71"N)
Band 1 Block=25070x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-10000
```

Comment: I can't say about zoom levels but it seems that your Leaflet map is configured to have tile origin in wrong place. In TMS the origin is at the lower left corner https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification.

Comment: Thank you for reply @user30184. I think you are correct. The gdal2tiles.py install by default , it can't generate a TMS for leaflet. I found a modified version of gdal2tiles in [github](https://github.com/commenthol/gdal2tiles-leaflet) it perfectly shows how to find the optimal zoom level for converting to TMS.
I managed to display my geotiff in leaflet, but i still got multiple display when I zoomed to high level and a corrupted TMS. Do you know what is the problem with this? I just wondering is the corrupted image caused by the compression LZW

Comment: Is the Leaflet map that you talk about the one that gdal2tiles creates with the `-w leaflet`option?

Comment: yes, however , my gdal2tiles.py install by default the option

`Web viewer options:
    Options for generated HTML viewers a la Google Maps

    -w WEBVIEWER, --webviewer=WEBVIEWER
                        Web viewer to generate (all,google,openlayers,none) -`

is show as this. I can't choose leaflet . Is this relate with the version of gdal?

Comment: I suppose so. But how can you use the Leaflet option if you do not have it available?

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/commenthol/gdal2tiles-leaflet) has a gdal2tiles.py modified added a -l option for leaflet. I use it with the author formulae for calculating the best zoom level TMS.  Btw could you tell me which version of gdal or any link to install it? I'm currently using macOS `brew install gdal` with python binding. I hope to use newer version in python in Ubuntu or macOS.

Comment: The trunk version of gdal2tiles.py is here https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal2tiles.py. Try if it works with your GDAL and Python versions.

Comment: @user30184 thanks for the link. However I tried to install with brew install gdal --head for the trunk version it shows this error
`Error: inreplace failed
frmts/jpeg2000/jpeg2000_vsil_io.cpp:
  expected replacement of "stream->bufbase_ = JAS_CAST(uchar *, buf);" with "stream->bufbase_ = JAS_CAST(u_char *, buf);"`. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I meant that try just with that new version of the gdal2tiles.py with your current installation. It is only a Python script.

Answer (score 4):

I had a case like this, went through gdal2tiles.py source for inspiration and wrote this Python script:

```
from osgeo import gdal

def get_optimal_zoom_level (geo_tiff_file_name):
  geo_tiff = gdal.Open(geo_tiff_file_name)
  geo_transform = geo_tiff.GetGeoTransform()
  degrees_per_pixel = geo_transform[1]
  radius = 6378137
  equator = 2 * math.pi * radius
  meters_per_degree = equator / 360
  resolution = degrees_per_pixel * meters_per_degree
  pixels_per_tile = 256
  zoom_level = math.log((equator/pixels_per_tile)/resolution, 2)
  MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL = 20
  optimal_zoom_level = min(math.floor(zoom_level), MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL)
  return optimal_zoom_level
```

In your case you'd call

```
get_optimal_zoom_level('[image.tif]')
```

and it should return deepest zoom level that still makes sense to tile at.

Note: This is meant to work for imagery not too far from the Equator and WGS 84 coordinate system. You may want to tweak it if your imagery is closer to poles.

Edit: My GeoTIFF unit was degree, so this code assumes unit is a degree. Your unit is meter, you'll have to tweak it for that, too.